# How do i get rid of the border of background color in blur effect CSS

Tags: html, css, css-filters

when i hover over the image i want the image to blur out and enlarge like it does, but there's this border that appears and disappears before the animation ends that is correlated to the background color of my page, how do i get rid of it?  (this is just the part of the code with the issue) it only happends if the background color is active

```css
/*General classes*/

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Play:wght@400;700&display=swap");
* {
  background-color: rgb(44, 40, 40);

  font-family: "Play", sans-serif;
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}




.project__img{
    max-width: 100%;
    transition: all 500ms ease ;
}

.project__wrapper{
    display: flex;
    padding: ;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 80px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.767);
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;               /*img is overflowing it so we use this so it prevents it*/ 
    
    position: relative;     /*this is for my stupid background, its so it overlaps the bg and keeps the values above it */
   

}

.project__wrapper:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1c1d25;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 450ms ease;
    z-index: 10;
}

.project:hover .project__wrapper:before {
  
    opacity: 0.7;

}

.project:hover .project__img{
    transform: scale(1.07);
    filter: blur(20px);
   
   
    
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c8e4d183c2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="projects">
        <div class="container"> <!--adds margin on top and bottom-->
          <div class="row"> <!--adds max width to the sides-->
            
             <h1 class="section__title">Here are some of my <span class="text--purple">projects</span></h1>
             <ul class="project__list">
              <li class="project">
               <div class="project__wrapper" style="width: 600px;height: 600px ;">
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/aa/60/1e/aa601e512b1279ce8b080acc29e362d0.jpg" class="project__img" alt="">
               </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what border do you see? i see the opacity transitioning which creates the appearance of a band of black around the image before it finishes... may be due to the one transition: all under project__img

Comment: so, i was following a tutorial but the guide didn't add an additional background color, i did, what do i change the transition, do i put it somwhere else? thanks for the answer btw and sorry for the ignorance i just started coding a week ago

Comment: its the filter: blur(20px) that creates that border.. not sure how to resolve to what you are expecting to see but i would start there

Comment: Try this i added filter:blur(0px) as a starting point for the transitions and changed the transition: all 450ms ease; to match the other transition
.project__img{
    max-width: 100%;
    transition: all 450ms ease ;
    filter: blur(0px);
}

Comment: also 

.project:hover .project__img{
    transform: scale(1);
    filter: blur(20px);   
}

scale set to just 1 then it doesnt push the image out larger than the frame which i think made the border issue you seen as well

Comment: thank you so much for the help, Jamie, you stirred me in the right direction i didn't know where the issue was, it is indeed as you said it's in the filter so i ended up changing the whole tag

Answer (score 0):

i've ended up changing the whole tag as Jamie Garcia said above, the problem lies in the filter: blur(20px) that creates that border, still not sure how to fix that but this code does the exact same thing i wanted it to, keeping the border without making it disappear

```css
/*General classes*/

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Play:wght@400;700&display=swap");
* {
  background-color: rgb(44, 40, 40);

  font-family: "Play", sans-serif;
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}




.project__img{
    max-width: 100%;
    transition: all 450ms ease ;
    filter: blur(0px);
}

.project__wrapper{
    display: flex;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 80px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.767);
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;               /*img is overflowing it so we use this so this prevents it*/ 
    
    position: relative;     /*this is for my stupid background, its so it overlaps the bg and keeps the values above it */
   

}

.project__wrapper:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1c1d25;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 450ms ease;
    z-index: 10;
}

.project:hover .project__wrapper:before {
  
    opacity: 0.7;

}

.project:hover .project__img{
    -webkit-filter: blur(14px);
    filter: blur(14px);                 /*this works but its not tut way cuz it had wierd borders*/
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2,1.2,1);
    transform: scale3d(1.2,1.2,1);
   
    
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c8e4d183c2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="projects">
        <div class="container"> <!--adds margin on top and bottom-->
          <div class="row"> <!--adds max width to the sides-->
            
             <h1 class="section__title">Here are some of my <span class="text--purple">projects</span></h1>
             <ul class="project__list">
              <li class="project">
               <div class="project__wrapper" style="width: 600px;height: 600px;">
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/aa/60/1e/aa601e512b1279ce8b080acc29e362d0.jpg" class="project__img" alt="">
               </div>
</body>
</html>
```